# Qt Q_PROPERTY with template accessors

Tags: qt, templates, properties, moc

I'm aiming for a little bit more code reuse, while maintaining verbosity.

Consider the following sample code:

```
// qdot@defixio /tmp/test4 $ cat test.h
#include <QObject>

class Foo : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  // Q_PROPERTY(int bar1 READ bar<1>)
  // Q_PROPERTY(int bar2 READ bar<2>)

  public:
  template <int i> int bar() const;
};

// qdot@defixio /tmp/test4 $ cat test.cpp 
#include "test.h"
#include <QDebug>


template <int i> 
int Foo::bar() const { qDebug() << "Template parameter" <<  i; } 

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.bar<1>();
  foo.bar<2>();
  return 0;
}
```

This one compiles and runs as expected.

In case you're wondering why I would like that - imagine a set of properties, DESIGNABLE, etc, but falling under the same "class" - in that case, I would like to have separate properties, using enum-templatetyped accessors.

Uncommenting the property definitions, results in the following moc error:

```
/usr/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. test.h -o moc_test.cpp
test.h:5: Parse error at "bar"
```

Any idea on how to properly mix templating and moc?

---

To answer cmannet85's comment, and add more insight - yes, that `moc` invocation generates `moc_test.cpp` from `moc.h`.

To test and demonstrate it further, I added another property

```
Q_PROPERTY(int baz1 READ baz1)
```

and the diff between moc_test.cpp before and after is this:

```
--- moc_test.cpp        2012-10-02 13:23:39.442333849 +0200
+++ moc_test_baz1.cpp   2012-10-02 13:23:29.822328462 +0200
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 /****************************************************************************
 ** Meta object code from reading C++ file 'test.h'
 **
-** Created: Tue Oct 2 13:23:39 2012
+** Created: Tue Oct 2 13:22:27 2012
 **      by: The Qt Meta Object Compiler version 63 (Qt 4.8.3)
 **
 ** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
@@ -24,17 +24,20 @@
        0,       // classname
        0,    0, // classinfo
        0,    0, // methods
-       0,    0, // properties
+       1,   14, // properties
        0,    0, // enums/sets
        0,    0, // constructors
        0,       // flags
        0,       // signalCount

+ // properties: name, type, flags
+       8,    4, 0x02095001,
+
        0        // eod
 };

 static const char qt_meta_stringdata_Foo[] = {
-    "Foo\0"
+    "Foo\0int\0baz1\0"
 };

 void Foo::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
@@ -76,6 +79,30 @@
     _id = QObject::qt_metacall(_c, _id, _a);
     if (_id < 0)
         return _id;
+    
+#ifndef QT_NO_PROPERTIES
+     if (_c == QMetaObject::ReadProperty) {
+        void *_v = _a[0];
+        switch (_id) {
+        case 0: *reinterpret_cast< int*>(_v) = baz1(); break;
+        }
+        _id -= 1;
+    } else if (_c == QMetaObject::WriteProperty) {
+        _id -= 1;
+    } else if (_c == QMetaObject::ResetProperty) {
+        _id -= 1;
+    } else if (_c == QMetaObject::QueryPropertyDesignable) {
+        _id -= 1;
+    } else if (_c == QMetaObject::QueryPropertyScriptable) {
+        _id -= 1;
+    } else if (_c == QMetaObject::QueryPropertyStored) {
+        _id -= 1;
+    } else if (_c == QMetaObject::QueryPropertyEditable) {
+        _id -= 1;
+    } else if (_c == QMetaObject::QueryPropertyUser) {
+        _id -= 1;
+    }
+#endif // QT_NO_PROPERTIES
     return _id;
 }
 QT_END_MOC_NAMESPACE
```

There is absolutely nothing to prevent moc from just copying over the entire bar<1> statements into the `QMetaObject::ReadProperty` switch statements - but it somehow barfs on the <> template tags.

Comment: AFAIK the `moc` is ran before the C++ preprocessor (to replace all the Qt keywords with 'real' C++), so template code is not expanded - and the `moc` can't do that itself.  That's what the parse error is referring to.

Comment: The main problem is `moc` using its own parser which recognizes only a subset of C++.

Comment: yeah, but I wonder how to get it to do the same to the template code - I don't think it needs any expanding at this step - if you substitute 'baz1' with 'bar<1>' in the moc_test.cpp, it works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moc` does not like template braces inside `Q_PROPERTY` declarations. You can do the following:

```
class Foo : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(int bar1 READ bar_1)
  Q_PROPERTY(int bar2 READ bar_2)

  private:
  inline int bar_1() const { return bar<1>(); }
  inline int bar_2() const { return bar<2>(); }

  public:
  template <int i> int bar() const;
};
```

The code generated by `moc` should be able to access private methods of your class, and this indirection should not induce any runtime cost since the compiler can inline the calls to `bar_N`.

You probably want to hide the declaration of `bar_N` in a macro.

Comment: how would I hide that declaration?

Comment: I would have done something like `#define BAR(N) inline int bar_##N() const { return bar<N>(); }`, but your solution of macroizing only `bar<N>` is cleaner.

Comment: Well, I would say that yours is cleaner - mine pollutes the global namespace, since there is absolutely no DEFINE that distinguishes compilation of moc-generated code from compilation of 'real' code.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I think I almost figured this one out. It's just evil.due to namespace pollution - and there seem to be no DEFINE in `moc_test.cpp` prior to including my header file.

merely defining

```
#define ___BAR1 bar<1> 
Q_PROPERTY(int bar1 READ ___BAR1)
```

did the job - I would however prefer if `___BAR1` was only defined during MOC run (easy) and during `moc_test.cpp` compilation.

Bracketing

```
#ifdef Q_MOC_RUN
#define ___BAR1 bar<1> 
#endif Q_MOC_RUN
```

hides the define from anything but moc, but it's irrlelevant - it's also hidden from gcc when it compiles moc_test.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Just put () around the reader function:

```
Q_PROPERTY(int bar1 READ (bar<1>))
```